# Limit DateTime strftime precision to milliseconds

Tags: perl, datetime, datetime-format

I'm working on a project which involves integrating with a 3rd party API. As part of the contract, I need to include a UTC date string in the below ISO format, within the XML body of the HTTP request:

> yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

I've been trying a few options in `re.pl` to generate a date string in the above format. So far, I've been able to come up with this:

```
use DateTime;

my $now_utc = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'UTC');

my $now_iso_format = $now_utc->strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%sZ');
```

When I execute these lines in `re.pl`, I get the date string in the format:

> 2022-02-07T03:55:22.1644206122Z

How do I limit the precision to milliseconds? As you can see, right now it's nanoseconds.

Comment: [%s](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) is not partial seconds, it's seconds since the unix epoch. Use `$now_utc->millisecond()` to obtain millis.

Comment: But you'll probably have to use `Time::HiRes` as well as what you're doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Details are listed on [strftime patterns](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#strftime-Patterns) page and `%N` is for fractional seconds digits

```
.. -> strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ');
```

Comment: Or simpler: `strftime('%FT%T.%3NZ');`